# Использование ORM Realm с RecylerView

Tags: java, android, realm

Доброго времени суток. 
Осваиваю ORM Realm. Столкнулся с непонятной мне ошибкой.
Имеется класс адаптера для recyclerView, вот кусок кода

```
List<Dog> dogs = Collections.emptyList();

public void addDog(Dog dog) {
    dogs.add(dog);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public RecycleViewAdapter(List<Dog> dogs) {       
    this.dogs = dogs;
}
```

Далее, вот сам класс Dog

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
    public class Dog extends RealmObject{

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return "!!! Name - "+name+" | Age - "+age;
    }
}
```

Добавление новых собак в бд происходит следующим образом

```
public void addDog() {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Dog dog = realm.createObject(Dog.class);
            dog.setName(nameDog.getText().toString());
            dog.setAge(Integer.parseInt(ageDog.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

, на данном этапе все ок.
После того как добавили в бд, приходит уведомление об этом, я смотрю что изменилось и пытаюсь изменить данные в адаптере RecyclerView, но тут выпадает досадная ошибка 
вот код в котором приходят уведомления

```
final RealmResults<Dog> puppies = realm.where(Dog.class).lessThan("age", 7).findAll();
puppies.addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> dogs, @Nullable OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            int[] s = changeSet.getInsertions();
            adapter.addDog(dogs.last());
        }
    });
```

Ошибка возникает вот тут `adapter.addDog(dogs.last());`

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported by 'RealmResults' or 'OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot'.
```

Получается что List dogs в конструкторе адаптара можно спокойно присваивать значение RealmResults. Но вот воспользоваться методом add у List dogs уже нельзя. Пожалуйста подскажите почему выпадает эта ошибка, как ее устранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RealmResults` хранит изменяющуюся в реальном времени выборку из БД. Засим в неё и нельзя добавлять элементы, т.к. этим занимается сама БД. Вам вообще не нужно вручную добавлять что-то в список. он сам автоматически добавляет/удаляет элементы. Засим вам надо в `onChange` лишь уведомить адаптер о изменениях данных.

```
final RealmResults<Dog> puppies = realm.where(Dog.class).lessThan("age", 7).findAll();
puppies.addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> dogs, @Nullable OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: все заработало, огромное спс, поставил лайк.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы все упростить, используйте **RealmRecyclerViewAdapter**. Тогда не нужно будет уведомлять об изменениях в данных. Просто работаете с базой, а список обновляется автоматически.

Пример реализации можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview/MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java).